# AngularJS restmod: POST request to Django REST of string with "?a=b"

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I am using `angular-restmod`to send `POST` requests to a `Django REST Framework` backend. But whenever a string containing `?` will result in a broken POST data (when received): For instance, suppose I am sending `POST` data

```
{"properties": "values", "status": "?a=3", "other properties": "other values"}
```

the backend will receive `request.data`

```
MergeDict(<QueryDict: {u'{"properties": "values", "status": "?a': [u'3", "other properties": "other values"']}>, <MultiValueDict: {}>)
```

where things starts to fall apart at `=`.

`PUT` methods works fine in these kind of cases. I wonder how to fix this?

========== EDIT ==========
In the end I found an old setting for `$http`:

```
# $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

which overwrites the default `JSON` content type of `restmod`. I removed it, and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do not know exactly how anuglar-restmod works, it looks like you are trying to send JSON-like data, but it's actually being sent as form-encoded data. When data is form-encoded, it is combined to form `key1=val1[&key2=val2...]` and sent as one long string in the request body.

So while you were expecting the JSON data to be sent as

```
{"properties": "values", "status": "?a=3", "other properties": "other values"}
```

It was really being sent as form-encoded data, taking the form of

```
{"properties": "values", "status": "?a=3", "other properties": "other values"
```

Which should make it somewhat obvious what your issue actually is: It's not *actually being form-encoded*. This is being broken up such that `{"properties": "values", "status": "?a` is the key and `3", "other properties": "other values"` is the value.

So part of this [may be the fault of the tools you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19884638/359284), but there is one easy way to fix it: [make sure you are using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17556083/359284).

Comment: Thank you. Indeed Chrome shows that POST data are sent in form data. Let me check how to modify it.